# How to clear screen in runtime in C++ using Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("*********");
    system("clear");
    printf("#####");
}
```

Usually it works but it is not working in Xcode.

Comment: _"but it is networking in XCODE."_ Did you mean to write _"but it is **not working** in XCODE."_? You should note that `clear` is a command to clear the terminal output which isn't available at all operating systems and terminals. I also doub't that `#include<conio.h>` will work properly on any modern c++ development environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is already another thread, which has been answered.
I recommend to tryout this answer: [Clear Screen in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348153/clear-screen-in-xcode/12306687#12306687)

The referenced CPP forum article is quite interesting as well.
(http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10515/)